# Stretching the Top Banner

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to make my header banner stretch / fit to the website's dimensions, however, I am unsure how to make this happen on every browser.

HTML5:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Play - Learn - Grow</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>

    <body class="body">

        <span class="text_h">
        Welcome to KUBE Toy Library!
        </span>

        <span class="banner_h">
            <img src="Images\Top_Banner.jpg" alt="Banner" height="150" width ="1240"/>
        </span>

        <nav>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="membership.html">Become a Member</a></li>
                <li><a href="borrow.html">Borrow Toys</a></li>
                <li><a href="policies.html">Our Policies</a></li>
                <li><a href="sitemap.html">Site Map</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <span class="banner_l">
            <img src="Images\Left_Banner.jpg" alt="Banner" />
        </span>

        <span class="banner_r">
            <img src="Images\Left_Banner.jpg" alt="Banner" />
        </span>

        <h2 class="headers">Welcome to the Home Page!</h2>

        <div class="container">

            Our aim is to provide the children of the community with an ever-changing variety of educational and fun toys to enhance
            their cognitive, social, emotional and physical development in the important first six years of their lives.

            <br><br><span class="Links">Be sure to check out our Wikispace site with more information <a href="http://mysocialmediatools-pn.wikispaces.com/">here</a>!</span>

        </div>

        <div id="content"></div>

        <div id="footer">
            Copyright &copy 2013
        </div>


      </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* Entire Document CSS */
html{
    height: 100%;
}
/* Header CSS */
.headers{
    color: #FFD89A;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
/* Body CSS */
.body{
    background-color: #61B329;
    height: 50%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.container{
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    width: 50em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 500px;
    height: 50%;
}
/* Navigation CSS */
.nav {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #00B2EE;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-width: 1px 0px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
}
.nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 14.28%;
    float: left;
}
.nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
/* Banner / Picture CSS / Text in Images */
.banner_l{
    float: left;
}
.banner_r{
    float: right;
}
.banner_h{
    positon: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.text_h{
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}
/* Footer CSS */
#footer {
 clear: both;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 10;
 height: 3em;
 margin-top: -3em;
}
#content {
    padding-bottom: 3em;
}
/* Link CSS */
a:link{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover{
    background-color: #028482;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:active{
    background-color: #FCDC3B;
    color: #AA00FF;
    text-decoration: overline;
}
.Links A:hover{
    color: #028482;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: underline overline;
}
```

If your wondering why this is being created, this is for a school assessment task, and all content is fictious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
* {margin:0; padding: 0;}
.banner_h {display: block; width: 100%;}
.banner_h img {width:100%}
```

Check the result out in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F3MhW/).